# Как подключиться к хостингу

Tags: ssh, hosts

Посмотрите картинку и скажите пожалуйста что мне с этим делать, по ftp я подключаюсь без проблем но это мне не понятно, я правильно понял что с этим нужно работать через линукс? У меня просто винда, в первые с таким сталкиваюсь[image: Данные для подключения к хостингу]

Answer (score 0):

Для SSH тебе клиент нужен например *putty*,
А остальные данные это доступы к сайту (админке), но чтобы туда попасть надо поменять записи в хост файле.

Если работаешь под Windows нужно идти по адресу
*C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc*,
там есть файл hosts, его можно редактировать только от имени администратора.
Вносишь туда данные которые тебе дали и готово.

P.S. это нужно, чтобы ты попадал не на ту версию сайта которая в продакшене, а на ту которая в разработке. Ну судя по контексту вопроса я так думаю.